# AutoHotKey: Open start menu on second monitor with windows key

Tags: autohotkey

I want to set the the windows key (or "super key" in linux) on my keyboard to open the start menu on the currently active monitor (**second monitor**) instead of the the primary monitor, which is the default.

I've made a [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script to do that, which remaps the left windows key to a function.

My problem is:
This function is also executed even when I use some Windows key hotkey combination (like <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, etc...).

Is there a way to prevent that?
I mean: a way to execute this script only when I press (and release) the windows key alone, while letting me to use the others Win key hotkey combinations in the normal way.

Or is there a way to achieve this objective by a method other than AutoHotKey?

My script:

```
~LWin::{
    Send "{Blind}{vkE8}"
    CoordMode "Mouse", "Screen"
    MouseGetPos &orig_x, &orig_y
    Click 0, A_ScreenHeight
    MouseMove orig_x, orig_y
    }
return
```

---

### Edit:

I thought the [answer posted by Relax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77027638/9761768) solved the problem, but then I needed to change the script a little and found out my original script does'n t work. Besides, the `#HotIf (A_PriorKey ="LWin")` instruction does not prevent the win key to be remapped: the script was pressing the start menu after sending the key.

By reading [this thread](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=82&t=120240) I found out the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following answer

```
~LWin::Send "{Blind}{VKFF}"
~LWin up::{
    if (A_PriorKey = "LWin"){
        CoordMode "Mouse", "Screen"
        MouseGetPos &orig_x, &orig_y
        if (orig_x < A_ScreenWidth) {
            Click 10, A_ScreenHeight - 10
        } else {
            Click A_ScreenWidth + 10, A_ScreenHeight - 10
        }
        MouseMove orig_x, orig_y
    }
}
```

---

#### Update:

Sometimes I use 3 monitors, with the primary monitor in the middle or in the left.

The updated script bellow covers all these cases, including the right Win key.

Someone may want to change it to adapt to a particular case.

```
SendMode "Input" ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.

~LWin::Send "{Blind}{VKFF}"
~LWin up::{
    if (A_PriorKey = "LWin"){
        CoordMode "Mouse", "Screen"
        MouseGetPos &orig_x, &orig_y
        if (orig_x < 0){
            Click -A_ScreenWidth + 10, A_ScreenHeight - 10
        }
        if ((orig_x > 0) & (orig_x < A_ScreenWidth)) {
            Click 10, A_ScreenHeight - 10
        } 
        if ((orig_x > A_ScreenWidth) & (orig_x < 2*A_ScreenWidth)) {
            Click A_ScreenWidth + 10, A_ScreenHeight - 10
        }
        if (orig_x > 2*A_ScreenWidth) {
            Click 2*A_ScreenWidth + 10, A_ScreenHeight - 10
        }
        MouseMove orig_x, orig_y
    }
}

~RWin::Send "{Blind}{VKFF}"
~RWin up::{
    if (A_PriorKey = "RWin"){
        CoordMode "Mouse", "Screen"
        MouseGetPos &orig_x, &orig_y
        if (orig_x < 0){
            Click -A_ScreenWidth + 10, A_ScreenHeight - 10
        }
        if ((orig_x > 0) & (orig_x < A_ScreenWidth)) {
            Click 10, A_ScreenHeight - 10
        } 
        if ((orig_x > A_ScreenWidth) & (orig_x < 2*A_ScreenWidth)) {
            Click A_ScreenWidth + 10, A_ScreenHeight - 10
        }
        if (orig_x > 2*A_ScreenWidth) {
            Click 2*A_ScreenWidth + 10, A_ScreenHeight - 10
        }
        MouseMove orig_x, orig_y
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#HotIf (A_PriorKey ="LWin")

    ~LWin Up::{
        ; Send "{Blind}{vkE8}"
        CoordMode "Mouse", "Screen"
        MouseGetPos &orig_x, &orig_y
        Click 0, A_ScreenHeight
        MouseMove orig_x, orig_y
    }

#HotIf
```